# How to use DI within a class that hooks into TYPO3's Core?

Tags: typo3

Is there a way to use Dependency Injection within a class that hooks into the Core (using a Hook)?

Comment: Which TYPO3 version are you using and add your code which you tried using and doesn't work please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DI requires classes being managed with extbase objectManager. However, objects in hooks are usually instantiated with `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance`, which does not support DI.

However you could add a proxy layer between the hook and your service classes, managed with extbase objectManager.

Here's an example using constructor injection:

```php
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager;

class YourHook {
    public function yourMethod(value)
    {
        $this->objectManager = $this->getObjectManager();
        $yourService = $this->objectManager->get(YourService::class);
        $result = $yourService->process($value);

        return $result;
    }

    protected function getObjectManager()
    {
        return GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class);
    }

}

class YourService {
    public function __construct(OtherService $otherService)
    {
        $this->otherService = $otherService;
    }

    public function process($value)
    {
        return $this->otherService->doFancyStuff($value);
    }
}

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['typo3_hook.php']['hookName'][] = 'EXT:your_ext/Classes/YourHook.php:YourHook->yourMethod'
```

Comment: Thx! I did not think about this simple, yet effective possibility. This should make it easier to unit test hook related stuff.